# I want to get the Cartwright number or Doodson Number of each tide constituent. How to implement this using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there such a python library? Or should I calculate it myself? How should I implement it? I just want to map it into a dictionary.

I hope ocean experts can provide solutions
I can only find Doodson Number in books but I want to form a python library to use as constant

What is the calculation formula of Doodson Number? I am just getting started. I hope there is a good solution.